# Cognito throwing Username should be an email

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am attempting to build a lambda function connected to an API gateway POST method that will allow users to create and register cognito users within a given pool:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
  username = json.dumps(event["body"])

  try:
    response = client.admin_create_user(
      UserPoolId=user_pool,
      Username=username,
      TemporaryPassword="TemporaryPassword1234",
    )

    return response

  except ClientError as e:

        return {
            "statusCode": 400,
            "headers": misc.response_parameters_standard,
            "body": e.response["Error"]["Message"],
        }
```

The username in email format is given in the event body.

I have confirmed via logging statements that the username variable is being successfully extracted as a string in format "name@email.com"

I have confirmed that the lambda function has appropriate permissions to access cognito as admin.

On running this lambda, I am met with the ClientError of:

```
Username should be an email.
```

I have sent the username in the same format directly from the CLI and the userpool accepts an identical username without error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json.dumps` converts object -> JSON.

`json.loads` converts JSON -> object.

If the `event` is JSON, you want to convert JSON -> object so try `username = json.loads(event["body"])` instead.

If it isn't and you're just passing the username as a string, try `username = event[“body”]`.

Comment: Afraid this raises a  "JSONDecodeError"

Comment: Then your event isn’t JSON - what are you passing exactly as a body? If it’s not JSON just do `event[“body”]`

Comment: Simply passing event[“body”] resolved it, thank you. If you would like to amend your answer, I will mark it as a solution.

Comment: @RAH updated the answer to cover both cases